# Xcode 12.4 Linking error: Library not found

Tags: xcode

I am using xcode 12.4 and In a macOS/OSX project I am getting a linking error Library not found.
The mac os app is using a C++ library that is being successfully built in the xcode workspace, but the linker fails to find it
I have added that dependency Cpp library in the "Link binary with Libraries" (Build phases)

I think my Library search paths setting in Build Settings is not correct, linker search hardcoded path which was set on different machine where project was first built.

The output of workspace which includes the C++ library is in the Derived data, how can I specify derived data or Build path as variable and use it to point to C++ library folder , so that even on different machine project is built without searching any hard coded library paths ?
Thanks,
Ahmed